# How to get a new df constituted by partialy transposed fragments of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am struggling to get my dataframe transposed, not simply transposed but I want to limit the number of columns to the number of rows in index `slices`, in order to well explain my problem I give you my dataframe here :

```
df=pd.DataFrame({
        'n' : [0,1,2, 0,1,2, 0,1,2],
    'col1' : ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'col2' : [9.6,10.4, 11.2, 3.3, 6, 4, 1.94, 15.44, 6.17]
    })
```

It has the following display :

```
    n   col1    col2
0   0   A   9.60
1   1   A   10.40
2   2   A   11.20
3   0   B   3.30
4   1   B   6.00
5   2   B   4.00
6   0   C   1.94
7   1   C   15.44
8   2   C   6.17
```

From that dataframe I want to get the following  `new_df`:

```
        0   1   2
col1    A   A   A
col2    9.6 10.4    11.2
col1    B   B   B
col2    3.3 6.0 4.0
col1    C   C   C
col2    1.94    15.44   6.17
```

What I tried so far :

```
new_df = df.values.reshape(3, 9)
new_w = [x.reshape(3,3).T for x in new_df]
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(new_w[0])
df_1.index = ['n', 'col1', 'col2']
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(new_w[1])
df_2.index = ['n', 'col1', 'col2']
df_3 = pd.DataFrame(new_w[2])
df_3.index = ['n', 'col1', 'col2']
new_df = df_1.append(df_2)
new_df = new_df.append(df_3)
new_df[new_df.index!='n']
```

The code I tried works but it looks long, I want another shorter solution for that.

Any help from your side will be highly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identify the unique values in "col1" with [`factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html), then [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) to combine the two columns and [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
(df.assign(idx=pd.factorize(df['col1'])[0]).melt(['n', 'idx'])
   .pivot(index=['idx', 'variable'], columns='n', values='value')
   .droplevel('idx').rename_axis(index=None, columns=None) # optional
)
```

Or with [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
(df.assign(idx=df.groupby('n').cumcount()).melt(['n', 'idx'])
   .pivot(index=['idx', 'variable'], columns='n', values='value')
   .droplevel('idx').rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
)
```

Output:

```
         0      1     2
col1     A      A     A
col2   9.6   10.4  11.2
col1     B      B     B
col2   3.3    6.0   4.0
col1     C      C     C
col2  1.94  15.44  6.17
```

Comment: You always amaze me mozway - I tried to melt and pivot, but could not get the right output, but I can see now that `factorize` was what I was missing. Awesome answer !!

Comment: @ScottC I think you can also `cumcount` on `n` instead, see update ;)

Comment: Its funny, because I tried `groupby` also, but could not think of the right aggregation - thank you for showing that alternative.

Comment: Hi @mozway , thanks for the answer,  the code with `groupby.cumcount` works, while the first code gave me the error : `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

Answer (score 1):

In the following method I extract 3 dataframes so that I can concatenate them later. I have to do a bit of manipulation to get it into the correct format:

- Select every 3 rows
- Transpose these 3 rows
- Get the column names from the first row
- Remove the first row
- append to a list

Once I have the 3 dataframes in a list, they can be concatenated using `pd.concat`

#### Code:

```
t_df = []
for i in range (int(len(df)/3)):  
    temp = df.iloc[i*3:(i+1)*3].T
    temp.columns = temp.iloc[0]
    temp = temp[1:]
    t_df.append(temp)

new_df = pd.concat(t_df)
print(new_df)
```

#### Output:

```
n        0      1     2
col1     A      A     A
col2   9.6   10.4  11.2
col1     B      B     B
col2   3.3    6.0   4.0
col1     C      C     C
col2  1.94  15.44  6.17
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic is:

- Group by "col1" and iterate the grouper.
- Transpose the sub_group obtained in iteration.
- Concat all transposed sub_groups.

```py
df_arr = []
for key, sub_df in df.groupby("col1"):
  df_arr.append(sub_df.set_index("n").T)

df = pd.concat(df_arr).rename_axis("", axis="columns")
```

Output:

```
         0      1     2
col1     A      A     A
col2   9.6   10.4  11.2
col1     B      B     B
col2   3.3    6.0   4.0
col1     C      C     C
col2  1.94  15.44  6.17
```

Comment: thanks your code is short and helpful, however it didn't work once I rise `n` column to [0,1,2,3] values instead of [0,1,2]